# ¿Cómo agregar correctamente tipografías de Google Fonts?

Tags: html5, css3

Tengo una duda.
Al utilizar tipografías de Google Fonts, ya sea por el metodo import en CSS o en , al momento de recargar la pagina se logra apreciar durante un segundo la tipografía por defecto del navegador.

```
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2
```

family=Montserrat:wght@300&display=swap');

¿Como se puede mejorar la carga de tipografías utilizando Google Fonts?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Importalo mediante html y agrega el atributo !important

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="urlDeLaFuente" type="text/css" !important />
```

Eso bastará

Comment: Usar important es una muy mala práctica, por qué se la estás recomendando?

Comment: Si pero el chico quiere que se cargue la fuente antes de ver el resto y important ayudara en ese caso pues para el es importante que se vea siempre la tipografia